# Пунктуация в эпиграфе

Tags: пунктуация

Эпиграфом главы служит кусочек библейского стиха. Вот стих: "Он сказал им: когда молитесь, говорите: Отче наш, сущий на небесах! да святится имя Твое; да приидет Царствие Твое; да будет воля Твоя и на земле, как на небе..." (Лук. 11:2). В эпиграф войдет фраза: "да будет воля Твоя и на земле, как на небе...". Как правильно оформить начало и конец эпиграфа? Должен ли он начинаться с большой буквы и должны ли в начале стоять многоточие. А в конце? Если исходить из правил оформления цитат, он может выглядеть так:

```
                                ...Да будет воля Твоя и на земле, как на небе...

                                                         Евангелие от Луки 11:2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формально вы правы, но по факту при оформлении эпиграфов (а библейских цитат - в особенности) многототочия до и после законченного куска текста обычно опускают.

В нехудожественных текстах источник можно указывать в соответствии со старыми рекомендациями - Лук.11:2.